# Using std::chrono::duration::rep with printf in 32bit and 64bit programs

Tags: c++, c++11, io, long-integer, c++-chrono

There is this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  auto d = std::chrono::microseconds(1).count();
  printf("%lld", d);
  return 0;
}
```

When this is compiled in 64bit mode, then there is a warning:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:7:19: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
>    printf("%lld", d);
>                    ^
> ```

This warning is not present when compiling in 32bit mode (with -m32 flag). It looks like that `std::chrono::duration::rep` is of type `long int` in 64bit programs and `long long int` in 32bit programs.

Is there a portable way to print it like `%zu` specifier for `size_t`?

Comment: why not use `std::cout` since you're using C++?  It will be portable.

Comment: This is not an option. :( This is just a simplified example of the problem.

Comment: `long long int` instead of auto? naaaah, that's not c++11 enough. Although when using it with printf I would rather go for `int64_t`

Comment: It looks that printf("%" PRId64 "", d); fixes the problem. It seems that this std::chrono::duration::rep is a 64bit number in 32 and 64 bit systems, so just that should be ensured.

Comment: Perhaps you might be allowed to use a temporary c++'ism.  "std::ostringstream ss; ss << d;" to create a string, then a simple "printf("%s", ss.str().c_str());"    Portable, and not using std::cout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using the `auto` qualifier, use a fixed size integer int64_t.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cinttypes>

int main()
{
    int64_t d = std::chrono::microseconds(1).count();
    printf("%" PRId64 "\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As you said that the usage [of `std::cout`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is not an option you can cast the value to the smallest needed data type<sup>1</sup> here it's `long long int`<sup>2</sup> and use the corresponding conversion specifier:

```
printf("%lld", static_cast<long long int>(d));
```

To avoid the explicit cast you can also use the data type directly instead of the [auto specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
long long int d = std::chrono::microseconds(1).count();
printf("%lld", d);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> With smallest needed data type I mean the smallest type that can represent the value in both implementations.
<sup>2</sup> The `long long int` type has to be at least 64 bit wide, [see here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/8051589).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use [`std::cout`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/), since you are in C++. This will be portable.

---

However, if you must use printf, change this:

```
printf("%lld", d);
```

to this:

```
#include <cinttypes>
printf("%" PRId64 "", d);
```

Another approach would be to cast `d` to the highest data type (which can hold both types), like this:

```
printf("%lld", static_cast<long long int>(d));
```

Comment: The OP is asking for something that will work if it is a `long int` or a long long int`.  I don't see how `printf("%ld", d);` satisfies that.

Comment: I've reread the question and now I don't think my suggestion is needed.  I was going to suggest converting to a string which will future proof it but the OP seems to only be concerned about 32 and 64 bits, not a possible future 128 but type.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast it to `long long int` before printing:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  auto d = std::chrono::microseconds(1).count();
  printf("%lld", static_cast<long long int>(d));
  return 0;
}
```

But it seems me that it is better to use `std::cout`

Answer (score 2):

A portable (i.e. C++) approach to consider, that does not use std::cout

```
 {
   // create a string:
   std::ostringstream ss; 
   ss << d;" 
   // then
   printf("%s", ss.str().c_str());
 }
```

or perhaps

```
 {
   printf("%s", std::to_string(d).c_str() );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the warning you can cast d to long long int.

```
printf("%lld", static_cast<long long int> (d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not directly related to the 32/64 bit problem at hand, but some of us are on embedded systems with odd output consoles and C++ libraries. (Plus we know that if we have to do any serious output formatting, printf is saner than iomanip!)

Anyway, this prints the guts of a duration and may be useful for debugging. Modify to taste.

```
template<typename Rep, typename Ratio>
printf_dur( std::chrono::duration< Rep, Ratio > dur )
{
    printf( "%lld ticks of %lld/%lld == %.3fs",
            (long long int) dur.count(),
            (long long int) Ratio::num,
            (long long int) Ratio::den,
            ( (Ratio::num == 1LL)
              ? (float) dur.count() / (float) Ratio::den
              : (float) dur.count() * (float) Ratio::num
            )
         );
}
```